# Various scales of infinite

Tags: cosmology, spacetime, space-expansion, universe, big-bang

I was reading a great answer by John Rennie earlier (and took a mental note of the question which I must have mislaid). I wanted clarification by comment so I thought I could look it up amongst John's answers but he has 191 **pages** of answers. Needle in a haystack.

John explains that in relation to inflation and expansion if we plotted out a grid of points 1 light-year apart in present time it would be a grid of infinite size - and if we went back in time to the Big Bang and plotted out a grid of the same points less than a nanometer apart it would still be of infinite size.

I really wanted to ask why we assume the Universe is infinite in this way?

Comment: Tip: Check the right margin for duplicates.

Comment: It all boils down to $0 \neq 0^+$. If the initial scale parameter $a = 0$ instead of $a = 0^+$, it will stay hopelessly at $0$, just ask Biden.

Comment: @MadMax - What happens if Biden and friends sit too long? Do they get BadBax?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I really wanted to ask why we assume the Universe is infinite in this way?

We assume that the universe is infinite because we have observational evidence that it is spatially *flat*, or very nearly so.

John was talking about a spatially-flat ($k=0$) [Friedmann universe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Friedmann%E2%80%93Lema%C3%AEtre%E2%80%93Robertson%E2%80%93Walker_metric). (Such a universe is curved in space*time* but not in *space*.) This is today’s [standard cosmological model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambda-CDM_model). Highly detailed observations of the anisotropy of the [cosmic microwave background](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cosmic_microwave_background) by the [Planck satellite](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Planck_%28spacecraft%29) provide compelling [evidence](https://arxiv.org/abs/2002.06892) that the universe is in fact spatially flat, or very close to it. So John’s description of an infinite, flat, and stretchy spatial grid is consistent with current thinking.

Comment: If it really is infinite we have no relative size

Comment: There’s no problem with that.

Answer (score 1):

We assume that the universe is homogeneous and isotropic. In this case, the FRWL metric should also satisfy this condition. and this implies that if the universe is flat it must be infinite.

I am not sure about the case where we measure a local flatness however globally that's not the case. Think about the earth's surface maybe we are on a curved space but at the near points, it seems perfectly flat.